# highstock set tooltip text color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In highstock chart I want to display my custom tooltip. It's text color should be same as color of first serie.

How is it posiible to do?
This does not work:

```
function CustomFormatter() {
  var s = "";
  var items = this.points;
  for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    s += items[i].point.name + ': ' + '<b>' + items[i].point.y + '</b>' + '<br>';
  }

  return '<span style="color: ' + options.colors[1] +'">'
       + Highcharts.dateFormat(' %a, %d %b %y', items[0].point.x)
       + '</span>' + '<br>' + s;
}
```

Thanks,
Zhenya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter and get color from series object `this.series.color`

http://jsfiddle.net/AfPKq/